# RG Flow and Bound State DOF

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, degrees-of-freedom

I have a question regarding how one should view resonance modes in QFT's along the RG-flow, and  their effect on $c$.  Note that I'm somewhat new to the ideas of RG-flows and CFT's.  According to the $c$-theorem, there's a number $c$ that monitors my active degrees of freedom.  So if in the IR, my EFT is trivial then $c=0$; however, as I approach scale $\Lambda_P$ where I must integrate in a particle $P$, then $c$ smoothly interpolates between 0 and the new number of DOF, $C \geq 0$.  For something like the Higgs setup, this makes sense to me, since there are no bounds states and a truly new particle appears.  However for QCD, the appearance of bound states in the IR (i.e. bound states of quarks/gluons) seems more subtle to me.

1.) Technically speaking I should be "losing" degrees of freedom/states as I integrate in the quarks because I see that the resonances aren't fundamental fields but instead are bound states that really cannot be active above $\Lambda_{\text{QCD}}$.  For instance if I computed $c$ for QCD in the UV, I would have thought I would have just ended up with  the DOF of classical YM, since those are the active DOF.

2.) But for $c$ computed at $\Lambda \gg \Lambda_{\text{QCD}}$, it should count all of the DOF along the RG flow from zero to the UV, and must include all of the bound states/resonances at or below $\Lambda_{\text{QCD}}$.  This means that the $c$ of the UV-CFT (here copies of quantum Maxwell with decoupled fermions) would have nothing to do with the $c$ of the quantum YM, which would **also** know about the resonances.

One of these two intuitions must be wrong, and it's surely because my understanding of $c$ is too naive.